# Calculate running total with condition in R

Tags: r

i want to calculate running total in the column of invested money....my condition is if buy_indicator==BUY and sell_indicator==HOLD then my invested money value should be negative of close_price*100 where 100 is volume of shares which is constant.....else if buy_indicator==HOLD and sell_indicator==SELL then my invested money value should be positive of close_price*100......else  buy_indicator==HOLD and sell_indicator==HOLD then it should contain the previous row value....

my dataset looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI3pw.png)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/error:s it cannot be copied, searched (SEO), breaks screen-readers, and may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. If you could please post the output from `dput(x)` (where `x` is a not-too-large portion of the data) and whatever code you've tried so far. It also may help (if unclear) what your expected output is given the sample data.

Comment: please provide reproducible examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to generate the columns with +1 or -1, that you can then multiply by 100*close prices. example:

```
positiveorneg <- ifelse(buy_indicator==BUY&sell_indicator==HOLD, -1, 1)
moneytoinvest <- positiveorneg*100*closeprice
```

You can then use `cumsum` to get the hopefully positively trended line of your money.

```
mymoney <- cumsum(moneytoinvest)
```

Don't spend it all in one place.

EDIT: if you have more than one condition you can embed `ifelse` statements:

```
ifelse(buy_indicator==BUY&sell_indicator==HOLD, -1, ifelse(buy_indicator==HOLD&sell_indicator==SELL, 1, 0))
```